# Are Landsat 8 C2L2 products ready to use?

Tags: landsat

If we download Landsat 8 Collection 2 Level 2 products, do they need configuration using Quality Assessment Bands before use?

Answer (score 0):

If by configuration you mean quality control, then yes.

Table 6-2 in [Landsat's User guide](https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-8-9-collection-2-level-2-science-product-guide) provides all the necessary information for interpreting the QA values after you convert them from decimal to binary.

For instance a QA value equal to 21284 (0101010101000000) means: *Image data; land; clear (no cloud, cirrus, shadow or ice, land)*.

Comment: I still can't understand how to use QA bands with ArcGIS in order to do the quality control. May you please explain ? @pan